# Sending a message through discord.py after message edit check

Tags: discord.py

I have a function that checks if 'your' is changed to 'you're' and I am having trouble having the bot send a message after this check. What is the proper way to do this? (I want this to apply to all channels.)

```python
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before,after):
    if(before.content == "your" and after.content == "you're"):
        # I want to send message here

client.run('Token') # I have my token here
```

Comment: What changes 'your' to 'you're'?

Answer (score 0):

Add ctx into the parameters `(before,after,ctx)`, and
then put in `await ctx.send("message")` where you want your message to send.

Answer (score 0):

the parameters `before` and `after` are of type [discord.Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20message#discord.Message). `discord.Message` has an attribute [`channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20message#discord.Message.channel), with which you can use the function `send`.

```
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
   if before.content == 'your' and after.content == "you're":
      await before.channel.send(send_whatever_you_want)
```